# Grails - Finding itemized param in params list

Tags: grails

What is the correct syntax for this. I want to find the value for the select of, say, x_2:

```
<g:select name="x_${personInstance.id}" from="${allPeople}" value="" />
```

Controller:

```
params.x_it
```

it is the current spot in a loop that I am running through. I need to figure out how to write that params.x_2 with the it 'wildcard'. It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this in your controller :

```
params["x_${personInstance.id}"]
```

Comment: Thanks - I just had to add a toString call to the end to get the value.